# Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN $200 USD credit available shows up for me

Tags: azure

I see the below message when I click CreditStatus link on top of my azure portal page..Can anyone tell me if I am charged the said amount ?

Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN $200 USD credit available
26 Days remain until your credit expires

I guess i have MSDN subscribtion because I do have Windows Store Dev registration..

Please redirect me to a proper forum if this is not relevant.

Comment: Are you an MSDN subscriber? because subscribers get free credits every month.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about billing by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an MSDN subscription, you receive Azure benefits as part of the package. The current implementation of this is to give your X dollars (200 for your subscription level) to use however you like. That can be VMs, Cloud Services, Service Bus Messages, or even SQL Azure resources. In the past, the allocation for a fixed amount of each. The new mechanism works much better since everyone is going to use the Windows Azure offerings in a different way.

So will you be charged? Not specifically for the $200, but you did pay for it as part of your MSDN subscription.

Comment: As one additional comment, last I checked you have to _explicitly_ go into your account settings and _turn on_ the ability to exceed your credited dollars. This means that you won't be charged even if you spin up 20 large vms and leave them running. The VMs will be stopped automatically once the credit runs out if you haven't opted into paying for the service, but you can't accidentally start paying a bill for your azure usage.